# TypeError: Operator * not compatible with types int256 and uint256 --> contracts

Tags: solidity, error, code

Fairly new at this so there's probably an obvious answer. I was just playing around with an interest bearing contract. this below works out fine:

```
uint interestPerSecond = _interest * (_amount / 1e16); // _interest is uint256
```

But then I tried to change the data type of both interestPerSecond and _interest to int, so that i can try a negative interest rate. And the error popped up. Can't seem to find an explanation in the documentation

Can some one explain why this is?

Comment: Please, can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: From what you posted, it seems like the variable _amount is uint256. So you get an error because the operator can't multiply two different types of variables (unit vs int)

Comment: d'oh so it is the _amount. Thank you both!